can't set breakpoints in side-panel
I am updating an old extension so that it will now work in modern browsers (https://github.com/acypher/coscripter-extension)

I install the extension by using chrome://extensions/ and "Load unpacked".
I click on the "service-worker" link on the Extensions page to bring up its DevTools page.
Then I open a web page (usually https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerita_(crustacean), because it's short), and
click on my extension in the toolbar. This opens my sidePanel.
I control-click a word in the web page and select "Inspect", which brings up a second DevTools page. I select "ContentScripts" and display some of them.
I then control-click my extension's sidePanel, and select "Inspect". This brings up a third DevTools page.

My extension is designed to record a user's actions in the web page.
My contentPage captures the user's action, and sends a message to my sidePanel.
This used to (e.g. yesterday) work just fine.
But now,
When I set a breakpoint in the contentScript -- where it is about to send a message to the sidePanel script -- execution stops as expected.
However, my breakpoint in the sidePanel script -- where it receives the sent message -- is ignored.
Mac OS 14.6 (23G80); Chrome Version 130.0.6723.116 (Official Build) (x86_64)

It's either a bug in Chrome if it updated since yesterday or there's a problem in your code. Try using console.log or debugger statement instead.

Thanks. I was using console.log, but had forgotten about debugger
